# How can I access a method on a child elements script in Unity?

Tags: unity, c#, gameobject

I'm using Unity.  I have an empty elements called `GameElements` which I programmatically add child elements to (players can spawn these objects themselves in-game).

Within my script `Play.cs` I have a method to handle the onclick event when someone clicks the Play image/button.  I want to run through all of the child elements of my `GameElements` object and run the method on the script `Circle.cs` which is attached to those child elements.

Here is my `Play.cs`:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Play : MonoBehaviour
{ 
    public GameObject GameElements;
    public Circle CircleScript;

    public void OnMouseDown()
    {
        Debug.Log("Clicked!", gameObject);

        GameElements = GameObject.Find("GameElements");

        // Loop through game objects and init them
        Transform[] allChildren = GameElements.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
        foreach (Transform child in allChildren) {
            // do whatever you want with child transform object here
            Debug.Log("child...", child);
            CircleScript = (Circle) child.GetComponent(typeof(Circle));
            CircleScript.Init();
        }
    }
}
```

The click events do generate a Debug Log in console for the child objects as expected.

However I get the following:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Play.OnMouseDown () (at Assets/Game/Scripts/Play.cs:22)
UnityEngine.SendMouseEvents:DoSendMouseEvents(Int32)
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What is the value of `GameElements` here: `GameElements = GameObject.Find("GameElements");`?

Comment: Why don't you use `var circles = GameElements.GetComponentsInChildren<Circle>();` instead of iterating in transforms to get the Circle component? In that way you know you iterate on valid objects.

Answer (score 1):

`child.GetComponent(typeof(Circle))` is not finding a `Circle` component, and thus returning null. You don't check for null, you just assume success and call `Init` on the resulting reference.

This is probably *happening* because, as you note in [your own answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/163204/1430), [`GetComponentsInChildren`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentsInChildren.html) returns components of the given type in the invoking game object *and* its children.

Regardless, you may want write the loop in a way that you protect against a failure to find the `Circle`:

```
foreach (Transform child in allChildren) {
  CircleScript = child.GetComponent<Circle>();
  if (CircleScript != null) {
    CircleScript.Init();
  }
}
```

You can alternatively check if the `child`'s game object is the `GameElements` object simply using `==`. Both options are somewhat more robust than checking the *name*, since you may change the name elsewhere some day and forget to update this code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `foreach (Transform child in allChildren) {` iterates the children and the original object itself.  So, if I have 2 children, I get 3 iterations, the first being the parent.

I simply need to check the name isn't of the parent:

```
foreach (Transform child in allChildren) {
    // do whatever you want with child transform object here
    Debug.Log(child.name);
    if(child.name != "GameElements") {
        CircleScript = (Circle) child.GetComponent(typeof(Circle));
        CircleScript.Init();
    }
}
```